# Young man living abroad, never paid taxes. Would this simplify a renunciation?

Tags: united-states, european-union, europe, citizenship

I'm a young (20 years old) American (French dual citizenship) living in Europe currently considering renouncing my US citizenship. However, I'm quite intimidated by the amount of paperwork, especially regarding taxes.

That being said, I've never paid US taxes in my life as I've never really earned taxable income before, being as young as I am and never having a job that paid above the threshold. Would this simplify matters for me if I were to go to renounce? Is there still any papers I'd need to fill out in regards to taxes?

Thanks so much in advance everyone (:

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about citizenship, not finance.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you'd want to renounce a citizenship in the first place?  Seems like you're closing off some options and benefits that it provides.

Comment: @Steve-o169 US citizenship also comes with potentially significant tax burdens, as they tax you even when you're living elsewhere.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam is correct. As of right now I have no intentions of working or living in the states and I was thinking that if I renounce now, early, before I've filed tons of US tax papers, it may simplify the process significantly

Comment: Funny thing, for the same reason I'm wondering if I should apply for US citizenship.... Just make sure you're 100% certain you want to give it up before you do it, there really isn't a way to reverse that decision.